# Problems with latest versions (2.77-2.78) on AMD GPUs

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu, opencl

Sometimes I have to use a cheapo laptop I bought back in summer but it was still cool, because I could combine both the APU and discrete AMD graphics to render 2-3 times faster than the quadcore CPU would, until recently.

On version 2.77-2.78, the tiles corresponding to the faster GPU appear grayish, with just a silhouette of the render while on the latest 2.78a release the two GPUs can't seem to render together at all. If I go back to 2.76a however, all renders fine like it used to.

I've changed settings, uninstalled and installed video drivers and Blender, tried everything but still same results. What is going on?!!!

Comment: It is either no longer supported because something changed or the GPU is old and doesn't support new features, or it is a bug and should be reported to http://developer.blender.org/. Have in mind that AMD/OpenCL support is considered experimental and is not currently at the same support level as NVidia/Cuda, unfortunately

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I went to the dev. forum and there was a thread exactly about this; a guy had my identical issues on the same blender versions. Seems like a bug, hope they fix it soon because AMD is the only one that allows to magically link APU and discrete GPU essentially boosting your overall GPU rendering.